# How to I step through a .NET assembly stored in SQL Server (CLR)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I need to step through and debug an assembly uploaded to SQL Server.

The developer who created this project was kind enough to make the comments in the script:

```
-- Use the following line of code to create the assembly from a file when making frequent changes to the assembly during debugging.
CREATE ASSEMBLY asm_MY_NAME FROM 'C:\myDir\myDLL.dll'

-- Use the following line of code in order to debug CLR methods in this assembly.
ALTER ASSEMBLY asm_MY_NAME
ADD FILE FROM 'C:\myDir\myDLL.pdb'
```

I successfully run the following two statements on a freshly compiled DLL, but I have yet to figure out how to step through the code.

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlclr/archive/2006/06/29/651644.aspx) indicates all I have to do is attach

> to any client application that opens a database connection to SQL
>   Server

My project is a Web Applicaton.  I've tried attaching through chrome.exe to see if the debugger catches my breakpoint.

I also tried attaching to sqlservr.exe and that did not work either.

What could I be missing to be able to step through code?

**EDIT:**  Also tried aspnet_state.exe; no luck.

Comment: Do you have to attach the debugger to your web server?

Comment: @MikeChristensen Mike, I didn't even think of that (e.g. attaching to aspnet_state.exe)  till your comment; which makes much more sense than attaching to chrome. :P  Anyway, to answer your question (and answer it poorly), "I don't know."  I'm not even sure how this the assembly's sub is called.  I just know it happens when I run a report through our web app.  I will check the RDL to see if there's any reference in there. Perhaps I can call from previewing the report in our reports project.

Comment: Are you sure you allow SQL CLR Debugging on your server? and note that debugging sqlclr stops ALL managed threads on sql server. (so don't do this on production)

Comment: @FilipDeVos This statement has already been run:  sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE  .  This is all local; I would not test something I'm not sure about on a production server. :)

Comment: @FilipDeVos Ok...now I see what you're talking about in Server Explorer in VS.  Yes, I did that and attached to asp_state.exe.  Should that have worked?

Comment: ah ha!  got it!  attached to sqlservr.exe  @FilipDeVos Will you please put your comment in the form of answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you allow SQL CLR Debugging on your server? and note that debugging sqlclr stops ALL managed threads on sql server. (so don't do this on production)

The following steps are required:

- Set the option `Allow SQLClr Debugging` in the Visual Studio Server browser
- Assure that the **.pdb** files are uploaded on the SQL Server
- Run Visual Studio as Administrator
- Attach to the process `sqlserver.exe`